# Custom font is not working in device

Tags: angularjs, cordova, fonts, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have developed an android mobile application using the Ionic framework.I have used  custom font **Lato-Black** by refering this [blog](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/use-font-awesome-glyph-icons-ionicframework/).However it doesn't work on devices. In Chrome/Firefox,works well.

**style.css**

```
.text-font-white {
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato-Black';
}
@font-face {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Lato-Black';
        src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="text-font-white">Welcome</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS syntax is not correct, there is nested occurrence of `@font-face` in your code

```
.text-font-white {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato-Black';
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato-Black';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```